# NVD3 legend Show/Hide chart getting scale / zoom feature disabling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have 2 line chart shown side by side which has 5 lines being plotted on each chart. So there  are 5 legend for each of them. Unchecking each legend would hide the respective line specific to legend and optimize(May be zooming or scale) the chart with new scale measurement.

This is default functionality of legend. What i am looking for is ONLY just show/hide respective line. No other functionality  like zoom/scale so that user does get distracted by zooming as s/he is comparing 2 charts side by side. I hunted documentation but did not find these feature on/off information.

Comment: it sounds like your domains are being updated when you're hiding/showing your lines. You'll want to find that function and remove that features. To hide the lines you can simply set the fill-opacity to 0 on hide, and fill-opacity to 1 on show.

Answer (score 0):

Force X

List of numbers to Force into the X scale (ie. 0, or a max / min, etc.). The numbers tell the d3.js the values to use in the scale, rather than d3.js determining the values.

Force Y
List of numbers to Force into the Y scale (ie. 0, or a max / min, etc.). The numbers tell the d3.js the values to use in the scale, rather than d3.js determining the values.

Datatype: Array of Numbers (i.e. [0, 50]

Reference: http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html